# How to remove webpack dev-server from production build

Tags: webpack, production

I am getting following errors when I run my "production build". I tried to set the NODE_ENV=production.

```
warning.js:14You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'. This means that you are running a slower development build of Redux. You can use loose-envify (https://github.com/zertosh/loose-envify) for browserify or DefinePlugin for webpack 


dev-server.js:62 Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.
```

I have following webpack plugin.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    'process.env': {
                        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Your problem is probably not related to your plugin. please show your whole wepback configuration.